# simple cakephp problem

Tags: php, cakephp

I know this is a really simple thing that I really should know but I'm trying to learn cakephp without having done much php before. I've been told thats a stupid idea, but I'm doing it for fun and so I'm doing it.

I want to pass an array from one controller action to another controllers action and then pass it to the view. I have:

sponges_controller.php

```
$info = $this->data;
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'baths', 'action'=>'dashboard', $info));
```

baths_controller.php

```
function dashboard($info) {
    $this->set('info', $info);
}
```

and then

```
<?php echo debug($info); ?>
```

in the view for dashboard.

I've tried various ways but can't make it work. All it does is print out Array()

Plz help me! :) Julia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the passing data in different controllers but within the same controller we can do it just like a function call by writing something like this.

```
$this->function_name($info);
```

This will perfectly work as intended. I've not tried this type of data passing in different controllers function.

Comment: This works! to pass to a different controller you need only add the controller name, ie: $this->Controller->function_name($info); Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass data that way from one controller to the other as far as I know, at most you can concat a string to the action, like an ID for view or editing.

If you want to pass the info you could try setting it in the SESSION variable in the following way:

```
$this->Session->write('Info', $info);
```

And in your other controller you can check for it:

```
$this->Session->read('Info');
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like cake will not let you pass an array into a controller action. I set up a simple example and I got an 'array to string conversion error'. Is there a specific reason why you aren't just posting the data to baths/dashboard? I can think of a workaround for your problem, but it is quite messy.

8vius's solution above will definitely work.
Here is another way, but using sessions is probably a lot better

```
$str = http_build_query($info);
$this->redirect('/baths/dashboard?'.$str);
```

So then in your baths/dashboard action, you will have access to your data using the php $_GET array.
So if you originally had `this->data['name']` you can access it with `$_GET['name']`

Comment: This works fine for strings you can also do $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action'.$info)) which is a more proper manner because you don't have to correct your action path if it changes

Comment: @8vius good point. I use cakephp a lot, but I guess I never take full advantage of everything it can do. ( For example, often using Model->query() and writing my own queries instead of using Model->find() )