# CakePHP - Passing Data Between Models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is my last hope...I have been trying to figure this out all day and I am out of gas.  I have an appointment application that an operator inputs phone, business, name, and call result (Customers Controller).  The call result then goes to the Appointments controller.  Lets say the operator setups up an appointment, I then now need to setup an appointment for the customer I just entered.  But when I try and setup a new appointment for the new customer I just get sent back to the Appointments index view instead of the form.  What am I doing wrong?  I need some other eyes on this.  My development team has all been laid off and I am the last one left, so I don't have anyone to bounce ideas and code off.  Please help.  I don't even know if I am asking the right question at this point.

```
function step1() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout','Make a New Call');
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Customer->create();
        $this->data['Customer']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Customer->save($this->data)) {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The customer has been saved', true));
            //??? WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO GO TO THE APPOINTMENTS CONTROLLER WITH THIS CUSTOMER DATA
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The customer could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not finding your question very clear. Do you want to redirect somewhere? If so, what data do you need when you get there - the ID, the data you saved to the database, some other data (eg. session)? Your actions name (`step1`) suggests this is some kind of wizard where someone would fill multiple forms in succession, is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after saving the data

```
if ($this->Customer->save($this->data)) {
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('The customer has been saved', true));
     $id = $this->ModelName->getInsertID();
     $this->redirect("customers/index/$id");
```

Now you've the id and fetch the data over there.
Or if you want to pass the entire array to that function then try this link [simple cakephp problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197789/simple-cakephp-problem/7204818#7204818)

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I needed, but it got my juices flowing in the right direction and I am now able to move on.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get $customer ? it isn't initialize

so you can save data in session
but it isn't good idea

```
$this->Session->write('data',$this->data);
```

also uoy can transfer customer id to another controller like this

```
$this->redirect("/appointments /step2/{$id}/");

// this is in appointments controller
function step2($id = null){
  if($id){
    $this->loadModel('Customer');
    $customer = $this->Customer->findById($id);
  }
}
```

something like this, hope it helps

Comment: I updated the code a little bit and took that out.  I have no idea why that was there and didn't even notice it.  I am revisiting this code after a month of not touching it and I don't know what I was trying to do there previously.  It was probably left over code from something else I was trying.  Thanks.  If you could look over the code again and help I would appreciate it.